# consumer in one consumer poll 0 record

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, environment

The same code which means the exact same configurations for Kafka consumers.
In my local environment, the consumer works well and can poll lots of records, but in another testing environment, the consumer always poll 0 record.

- auto.offset.reset = earliest
- testing environment can connect to the Kafka broker (the nc -vz works)

Could anyone help with this problem? Any answer would be appreciated.

expecting: the consumer in the testing environment should also poll plenty of records